# How to resolve one to many relationship in core data in iOS 4.0

Tags: ios, core-data, ios4, one-to-many

I'm now developing an app on iPhone OS with core data, but when I add core data code into app, Xcode throw an error that "to-many relationship entity.relationship option requires iOS 5.0 or later"

How to deal with this problem? or is there another way to replace core data with low cost.

Some info:
Base SDK :iOS 5.0
Deployment Target : iOS 4.0

Thanks

Comment: Please post the exact error message instead of paraphrasing.

Comment: Sorry about confused, I have updated my question, Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not complaining about the relationship, it's complaining about an option you've set for the relationship.  Most likely, this is because you have selected the *Ordered* option for the relationship, which is only supported in iOS 5 and above.